# Save UIImage as jpg File in Photo Library Directory in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: file, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiimage, save

As I know this is Simple Approch to save it in a Photo Library. But It can save with custom filename.

```
var someImage = UIImage.FromFile("someImage.jpg");
someImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) => {
    var o = image as UIImage;
    Console.WriteLine("error:" + error);
})
```

But I want to save it with filename.jpg in the Photo Library.

I try so much code but nothing is getting help to me.

**Code 1 :**

```
var imageName = "/" + dicomId.ToString() + ".jpg";

var documentsDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath
                    (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);

string jpgFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentsDirectory, imageName); // hardcoded filename, overwritten each time
NSData imgData = dicomImage.AsJPEG();
NSError err = null;
if (imgData.Save(jpgFilename, false, out err))
{
    Console.WriteLine("saved as " + jpgFilename);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("NOT saved as " + jpgFilename + " because" + err.LocalizedDescription);
}
```

This code part goes to if condition but it can not save the Image.

**Code 2 :**

If using this part of Code

```
var documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPath.GetDirectories(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomain.User, true)[0];
```

It give you don't have permission to save image.

I try lots of thing on google and SO but nothing could help to me.

**Edit :**

**info.plist**

[image]

Any Help would be Appreciated.

Comment: did you add appropriate permission in plist file ?
specially Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

Comment: @saketkumar I have already Added permission..

Comment: In your title you say u wanna save png file , in question you say , u wanna save it with jpg .
in which format you wanna get it saved?

Comment: @saketkumar I update my question..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796218/ios-save-image-with-name  maybe help though it is in swift.

Comment: @ColeXia I already tried that but it says `you don't have permission`.

Comment: I see u don't have any problem with code per se ,
so it got to be plist permissions nothing more .   
paste your plist content in question

Also the path you get with image name appended at last

Comment: @saketkumar see my update question.

Comment: Filenames within the `Shared Photo Library` (Photos Framework) are not manageable. They are read-only artifacts within a PHAsset and can change  due to iCloud syncing, etc... If you need a way to track *your* apps images within the shared library assign custom metadata to the image.

Comment: how to set custom meta data to UIImage and save it to Photo Library

Answer (score 1):

How about using `UIImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum()`?

Usage is something like:

```cs
image.SaveToPhotosAlbum((uiImage, nsError) =>
{
    if (nsError != null)
        // do something about the error..
    else
        // image should be saved
});
```

Make sure that you have requested permissions before you try to save.

```cs
PHPhotoLibrary.RequestAuthorization(status =>
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case PHAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
        case PHAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
            // nope you don't have permission
            break;
        case PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized:
            // yep it is ok to save
            break;
    }
});
```

Edit: if you want more control, you need to use `PHPhotosLibrary`, which is an awful API...

```cs
var library = PHPhotoLibrary.SharedPhotoLibrary;

var albumName = "MyPhotos";

var fetchOptions = new PHFetchOptions();
fetchOptions.Predicate = NSPredicate.FromFormat($"title = {albumName}");
var assetsCollections = PHAssetCollection.FetchAssetCollections(
    PHAssetCollectionType.Album, PHAssetCollectionSubtype.Any, fetchOptions);

var collection = assetsCollections.firstObject as PHAssetCollection;

library.PerformChanges(() => {
    var options = new PHAssetResourceCreationOptions();
    options.OriginalFilename = "filename.jpg";
    var createRequest = PHAssetCreationRequest.CreationRequestForAsset();
    createRequest.AddResource(PHAssetResourceType.FullSizePhoto, image.AsJPEG(1), options);

    // if you want to save to specific album... otherwise just remove these three lines
    var placeholder = createRequest.PlaceholderForCreatedAsset;
    var albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.ChangeRequest(collection);
    albumChangeRequest.AddAssets(new PHObject[] { placeholder });
}, 
(ok, error) => {
    if (error != null)
    {
        // someone set up us the bomb
    }
});
```